# How to get title of top viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, title, visible

I want to get the title of the top viewcontroller so I can compare it to a string and take appropriate action based on this comparison. I'm currently doing the following but the title is always returned as null.

```
UIViewController *viewController = self.viewController.homeViewController;

while (viewController.presentedViewController) 
    viewController = viewController.presentedViewController;

NSLog(@"top viewController title %@", viewController.navigationItem.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.viewController.homeViewController.title);
```

The `title` property should be a property of the view controller itself.

Comment: self.viewController.homeViewController is just the root controller. there are other UIViewControllers on top of it. i'm looking to get the title of whatever is the top UIViewController. i've tried viewController.title w/o success. it comes back null.

Comment: i tried self.viewController.title, but that gave null as well. see my original example. thoughts?